# Alternatives to DeferredContentProvider for supporting filtering in tables with SWT.VIRTUAL

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

In my project, I have a `TableViewer` which needs to show more than 100,000 items and also filter them. Without `SWT.VIRTUAL` the table takes multiple seconds to display. When trying to use `SWT.VIRTUAL`, however, I have the following problem:

Just implementing `ILazyContentProvider` as one would usually do is problematic, since it is incompatible with the usual filtering mechanisms in `TableViewer` and I would therefore have to implement the entire filtering mechanism myself.

In my searches, I have found [`DeferredContentProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/deferred/DeferredContentProvider.html) which should solve the problem. But `DeferredContentProvider` still has many known [bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=DeferredContentProvider), one of which ([146799](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=146799)) definitely already affects me, so I cannot use that.

My question now is: Is there any good alternative I should look at, or do I myself have to implement `ILazyContentProvider` in a way that handles filtering on its own? If so, what are my chances of not running into the same problems the implementors of `DeferredContentProvider` ran into regarding refresh problems? Does anybody have any experience with something similar?

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I solved the problem by manually limiting the amount of items I show at once to 5000, and by recalculating the set of shown items as the user starts entering the filter criterion. This works, but it is a specifically tailored solution to my problem and not a real reusable generalized solution.