# Eclipse plugin add Filter to TableViewer in IRunnableWithProgress

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, tableviewer

I want to add a filter to a `TableViewer`. The Table can be large so this can take a while. While the filter is added i want to Show a progressbar so that the user is informed that there is a task on going. I cant access the `TableViewer` directly in the `IRunnableWithProgress` class so i am using a `Runnable` with `Display.getDefault().syncExec`.

The Problem is that the Progressbar is not showing up and the complete UI is unresponsive.

```
public class SearchFilter extends IViewerFilter {

    public SearchFilter(String filterName){
        super(filterName);
    }

    //Filtert die Tabelle nach eingabe des Suchfelds

    @Override
    public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {

        //wird für jedes Element in der Tabelle(Paket) aufgerufen

        PacketDecoder packet = (PacketDecoder) element;
        String tmpData = packet.getDecodedData().toLowerCase();

        //falls Paket nicht decodierbar ist
        if(tmpData == null || tmpData.equals(""))
            return false;

        if(tmpData.contains(searchText.toLowerCase()))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}

class EnterListener implements TraverseListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {

        if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {

if(searchText !=null && searchText.equals(text.getText()))
                return;

            searchText = text.getText();

            ProgressMonitorDialog progDialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(parent.getShell());
            SearchProgress progress = new SearchProgress();
            try {
                progDialog.run(true, false, progress);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class SearchProgress implements IRunnableWithProgress{

    @Override
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
            throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {

        monitor.beginTask("entferne Filter...", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                searchFilter.setUsable(true);
                //Falls searchFilter zuvor nicht gefunden
                //searchFilter setzen
                if(!foundFilter) viewer.addFilter(searchFilter);
                else viewer.refresh();
            }
        });
        monitor.done();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Display.syncExec` runs the code in the UI thread but the progress dialog needs the code to run in a background thread so this is not going to work.

For a large table you should look at using the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag for the table and use a content provider that implements `ILazyContentProvider`.

However a virtual table with `ILazyContentProvider` does not support filters or sorting so you will have to do that yourself in the content provider.

There is an existing class `DeferredContentProvider` that tries to provide filtering and sorting for virtual table but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23755960/2670892) for links to problems with this class.

Comment: so i looked into this. Filtering with `DeferredContentProvider` is not as flexible as with the `tableViewer`itself. I use serveral filter at one time wich can be easily added to the tabel with `addFilter` which makes a lazy loading even more reasonable with large tabels. this is frustrating. I see no other way than to use a `ILazyContentProvider`and manage the filtering at my own :(